# Прошу помочь разобраться в вопросе реализации аутентификации в REST

Tags: python, веб-программирование, rest, flask

Привет, всем!

Пишу веб-приложение на Python-е с применением микрофреймворка Flask. 
Сейчас передо мною стоит задача реализации механизма аутентификации пользователей и выдачи ресурсов только авторизованным пользователям.

Читая ресурсы:

- [How authentication works?](http://www.kaleidos.net/blog/295/stateless-authentication-with-api-rest/)
- [RESTful Authentication with Flask](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask)

У меня сформировалась "каша" в голове. Прошу поделиться своим опытом.

А пока у меня в голове понимание такое:

- Приложение должно работать строго по HTTPS
- Запросы к приложению должны содержать токены
- Приложение может содержать какой-либо URL вида 'my-service.ru/v1/token' передавая в HTTP POST-запросе username/password можно получить токен с действием на час

Смущает то что передача пароля в открытом виде, пусть даже и по HTTP(S). Но лучшего пока не могу придумать.

Как же все-таки соблюсти Stateless-ограничение и при этом правильно принять credentials от пользователя чтобы выдать ему токен?

**UPD**:
Верно ли что что HTTP аутентификация Digest-типа это сессионный тип аутентификации?

**UPD2**:
Некоторые подробности работы моего приложения:

- Мое приложение предназначено для работы с "роботами"
- Я завожу нового пользователя в базу данных о пользователях в ручную и выдаю credentials этому пользователю. Он в свою очередь настраивает своего "робота" для дальнейшей работы в автоматическом режиме без участия человека
- Весь принимаемый и передаваемый трафик будет шифроваться, по этой причине выбрана работа по HTTP(s)

Comment: "Смущает то что передача пароля в открытом виде, пусть даже и по HTTP(S). Но лучшего пока не могу придумать." - она всегда происходит в открытом виде. Можете передавать хэш пароля, конечно (и сохранять в базе хэш хэша), но это не обеспечивает большой защиты.

Comment: "Смущает то что передача пароля в открытом виде, пусть даже и по HTTP(S). Но лучшего пока не могу придумать." - по https это уже не "в открытом виде"

Comment: @dizballanze: так-то оно так. Просто я новичок в веб-разработке, а информация по ней слишком разрознена. Вот и каша в голове :)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле в аутентификации для REST нет ничего уникального. Вы работаете через протокол HTTP, у вас те же средства, что и в не-RESTful. "Каша" возникает возможно из-за путаницы терминов аутентификация/идентификация.
Для аутентификации вы посылаете что-то в параметрах запроса: например логин и пароль. В ответе получаете идентификатор доступа - токен, он может быть в куки.
Для последующей идентификации клиента в вашем распоряжении заголовки (куки) либо query-параметры запроса, как в любом HTTP приложении.

Вот здесь хорошо рассмотрено в общем виде:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158864/272885
и
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311981/272885

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что следует понимать: безотносительно каркаса, на котором ведётся разработка, в большинстве случаев используются стандартизированные методы аутентификации. В этом плане разница между каркасами только в том, на сколько доступны готовые варианты решения для того или иного типа аутентификации - батарейки. В каркасах с батарейками, часто ваша задача решается тривиально.

Второе: ваше приложение не обязано работать на HTTPS, однако, некоторые типы аутентификации этого требуют или настоятельно рекомендуют (ср. HTTPBasic и OAuth 2).

Третье: должны ли запросы содержать токены зависит от выбранного вами типа аутентификации. Продолжительность жизни токенов тоже зависит от допущений стандарта. С передачей паролей всё ровно также.

И помните, что для тех же OAuth и Basic совершенно не важно, какой именно тип ресурса вы защищаете - выдачу REST или обычную веб-страницу.

Comment: Мне в любом случае надо будет шифрование принимаемы и передаваемых данных. Как вывод HTTP(S) лучшее решение, чем применять еще доп.библиотеку, вызывать код шифрованию трафика. Уж лучше это сделать прозрачно для приложения.

Comment: @sys_dev А вариантов использования доп.библиотеки шифрования я и не рассматривал в ответе. Без сомнения, TLS, если он правильно приготовлен, на сегодня оптимальное решение.

Comment: Я откинул вариант с OAuth2 по той причине, что он требует участия человека, пусть и минимального. У меня же приложение для роботов ;) Пожалуй этот факт надо указать моем вопросе

Comment: Ну, OAuth2 это минимум 4 сценария авторизации, есть шанс, что один из них мог бы всё же подойти. Если это приложение действительно «для роботов», то роботы могли обойтись голым TLS с общением при помощи сертификатов %)

Comment: Не совсем понял Вашу мысль с сертфикатами. Можете ее раскррыть в в виде UPD-части в вашем ответе? Добавил в свой вопрос UPD2-часть

Comment: Приподраскрою здесь, вкратце это выглядит так: генерируются приватные ключи (при этом вы сами же и будете выступать в роли Certification Authority) для вашего сервера и робота (клиента), создаются сертификаты. После этого при каждом запросе робот выполняет проверку сертификата, если всё хорошо то общение продолжается, используя параметры шифрования, о которых договорились клиент и сервер.

Comment: Кстати, из вашего UPD2 видно, что OAuth2 вполне может подойти.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22768/discussion-between-sys-dev-and-idle-sign).